# jquery select2 work with dropdownlist asp.net server control

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

I am trying to use it with asp.net server run dropdownlist.
When asp.net control is rendered on the page it has different id something such as: "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlAgentName" although the dropdown list is declared in the code this way:

```
<asp:DropDownList Selected="True" ID="ddlAgentName" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown nostyle sel1" Width="100%" />
```

I am trying two scenarios:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
             $("#<%=ddlAgentName.ClientID %>").select2({
                minimumInputLength: 4
            });
            $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlAgentName").select2({
                minimumInputLength: 4
            });
        });
```

But none of them doesn't want to work. 
The rendered html output is:

```
 <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlAgentName" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlAgentName" class="dropdown nostyle sel1" Selected="True" style="width:100%;"></select>
```

I tried normal (non-server) select box and the jquery script works fine there.
Every advice will be welcomed.
Thanks in advance, Laziale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the `ClientIDMode` property.  That way you can ensure the name of the DDL is the same.

Alternatively, you can give it a unique class name and get to it that way, but that's a little hacky.